# SQL query from Toplink expression

Tags: toplink

I have a oracle.toplink.expressions.Expression expression object with me which has been created using oracle.toplink.expressions.ExpressionBuilder. I want to find its equivalent SQL query(say select emp.empname,emp.empId from employee emp) which will be fired eventually in order to fetch data. I want to find its equivalent Statement/PreparedStatement or anything which will help me obtain the raw SQL statement about to be fired.

For e.g.
Following is the toplink expression:

```
expressionBuilder.get("empName").equal("Eric");
```

and i want to get the equivalent SQL query:

```
select emp.empName,emp.emp_id,emp.sal from employee emp where emp.empName like 'Eric'
```

Please let me know if there is any API to get the sol. I tried the implmentation classes of DatabaseQuery but couldn't find any method which could accomplish this.

Below is the toplink expression with me :

```
Logical operator  AND 
   Logical operator  AND 
      Logical operator  AND 
         Logical operator  AND 
            Logical operator  AND 
               Logical operator  AND 
                  Logical operator  AND 
                     Logical operator  AND 
                        Relation operator  < 
                           Query Key minEffectiveBegDate
                              Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                           Constant Tue Feb 01 08:00:00 CST 2011
                        Relation operator  > 
                           Query Key maxEffectiveEndDate
                              Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                           Constant Sat Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 2011
                     Relation operator  < 
                        Query Key begDate
                           Query Key calculatedQuantityDataList
                              Query Key qtyClassificationDataList
                                 Query Key operationalQuantityDataList
                                    Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                        Constant Tue Feb 01 08:00:00 CST 2011
                  Relation operator  > 
                     Query Key endDate
                        Query Key calculatedQuantityDataList
                           Query Key qtyClassificationDataList
                              Query Key operationalQuantityDataList
                                 Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                     Constant Sat Jan 01 08:00:00 CST 2011
               Relation operator  = 
                  Query Key opsTrxClassification
                     Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                  Constant -5001579
            Relation operator  = 
               Query Key accountingCompany
                  Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
               Constant 1196
         Logical operator  OR 
            Logical operator  AND 
               Relation operator  = 
                  Query Key sourceRelatedNodeObjType
                     Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                  Constant -2094
               Relation operator  IN 
                  Query Key sourceRelatedNodeObjId
                     Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                  Constant [4187]
            Logical operator  AND 
               Relation operator  = 
                  Query Key dispositionRelatedNodeObjType
                     Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                  Constant -2094
               Relation operator  IN 
                  Query Key dispositionRelatedNodeObjId
                     Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
                  Constant [4187]
      Relation operator  = 
         Query Key qtyType
            Query Key operationalQuantityDataList
               Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
         Constant -5000328
   Relation operator  = 
      Query Key qtyStatus
         Query Key qtyClassificationDataList
            Query Key operationalQuantityDataList
               Base com.altra.common.data.OperationalTrxData
      Constant -5000316
```

I want the SQL equivalent like

```
select otd.operationaltrx_id,otd.accountingCompany from OperationalTrxData otd where minEffectiveBegDate > to_date('','') ...
```

Thanks,
Adithya.

Answer (score 2):

Using a ReportQuery to select the desired fields then "prepare" the query and print out the SQL that will be generated:

```
ExpressionBuilder emp = new ExpressionBuilder(Employee.class);
ReportQuery query = new ReportQuery(Employee.class, emp);
query.addAttribute("empName");
query.addAttribute("emp_id");
query.addAttribute("sal");

query.setSelectionCriteria(emp.get("empName").equal("Eric"););
query.prepareCall(session, new DatbaseRecord());
String sql = query.getSQLString();
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, which type of query are you talking about in the above solution ? I mean which query can be created using an expression ? I tried DataModifyQuery but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Gordon, which type of query are you talking about in the above solution ? I mean which query can be created using an expression ? I tried DataModifyQuery but it didn't work.

Below is what i tried:
DatabaseQuery query = new DataModifyQuery(expression.toString());
query.prepareCall(getSession(), new DatabaseRecord());
String sql = query.getSQLString();

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a ReportQuery.

```
ExpressionBuilder emp = new ExpressionBuilder();
ReportQuery query = new ReportQuery(Employee.class, emp);
query.addAttribute("empName");
query.addAttribute("emp_id");
query.addAttribute("sal");

query.setSelectionCriteria(emp.get("empName").equal("Eric"););
List reports = (List) session.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: It was just an example I had given..I don't know the attributes I will be fetching; I only have the expression with me. Using the expression I want to fetch the SQL query which will be fired i.e. I want the equivalent SQL query of the toplink expression I have with me.