# Expression Builder to SQL Query

Tags: sql, expression, toplink

I know, that similiar post was posted already ([SQL query from Toplink expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401720/sql-query-from-toplink-expression)), but I didnt find an answer there. I would like to get SQL query from Expression Builder expression:

I have

```
Expression exp = builder.get(NUMBER.getAttributeName()).equal(getNumber());
```

and I want to see the `SELECT` statement, like `(Select * from table WHERE number=....)`

Or is it possible to execute the expression from Expression Builder without session? (I know that when I used `query.prepareCall(session, new DatabaseRow())` I can obtain statement, but I just need to avoid using session. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the Session (what are you going to execute it on without a Session???).

```
query.prepareCall(session, new DatabaseRow())
```

This is how you get the SQL, you need to create a ReadAllQuery with the expression to be able to get the SQL (an Expression is just a where clause).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that i wasnt able to create session because I couldnt register my project. And that was because I miss one line of code in my Project.class

```
 setName(APPLICATION_NAME);
```

After this, I was able to create session and execute query. Thank you anyway